# What is so bad with goto when it's used for these obvious and relevant cases?

Tags: php, goto

I have always known that `goto` is something bad, locked in a basement somewhere never to be seen for good but I ran into a code example today that makes perfect sense to use `goto`.

I have an IP where I need to check if is within a list of IPs and then proceed with the code, otherwise throw an exception.

```
<?php

$ip = '192.168.1.5';
$ips = [
    '192.168.1.3',
    '192.168.1.4',
    '192.168.1.5',
];

foreach ($ips as $i) {
    if ($ip === $i) {
        goto allowed;
    }
}

throw new Exception('Not allowed');

allowed:

...
```

If I don't use `goto` then I have to use some variable like

```
$allowed = false;

foreach ($ips as $i) {
    if ($ip === $i) {
        $allowed = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$allowed) {
    throw new Exception('Not allowed');
}
```

My question is what's so bad with `goto` when it's used for such obvious and imo relevant cases?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44739/discussion-on-question-by-php-nub-qq-what-is-so-bad-with-goto-when-its-used-for).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

GOTO itself is not an immediate problem, it's the implicit state machines that people tend to implement with it. In your case, you want code that checks whether the IP address is in the list of allowed addresses, hence

```
if (!contains($ips, $ip)) throw new Exception('Not allowed');
```

so your code wants to check a condition. The algorithm to implement this check should be of no concern here, in the mental space of your main program the check is atomic. That's how it should be.

But if you put the code that does the check into your main program, you lose that. You introduce mutable state, either explicitly:

```
$list_contains_ip = undef;        # STATE: we don't know yet

foreach ($ips as $i) {
  if ($ip === $i) {
      $list_contains_ip = true;   # STATE: positive
      break;
  }
                                  # STATE: we still don't know yet, huh?                                                          
                                  # Well, then...
  $list_contains_ip = false;      # STATE: negative
}

if (!$list_contains_ip) {
  throw new Exception('Not allowed');
}
```

where `$list_contains_ip` is your only state variable, or implicitly:

```
                             # STATE: unknown
foreach ($ips as $i) {       # What are we checking here anyway?
  if ($ip === $i) {
    goto allowed;            # STATE: positive
  }
                             # STATE: unknown
}
                             # guess this means STATE: negative
throw new Exception('Not allowed');

allowed:                     # Guess we jumped over the trap door
```

As you see, there's an undeclared state variable in the GOTO construct. That's not a problem per se, but these state variables are like pebbles: carrying one is not hard, carrying a bag full of them will make you sweat. Your code will not stay the same: next month you'll be asked to differentiate between private and public addresses. The month after that, your code will need to support IP ranges. Next year, someone will ask you to support IPv6 addresses. In no time, your code will look like this:

```
if ($ip =~ /:/) goto IP_V6;
if ($ip =~ /\//) goto IP_RANGE;
if ($ip =~ /^10\./) goto IP_IS_PRIVATE;

foreach ($ips as $i) { ... }

IP_IS_PRIVATE:
   foreach ($ip_priv as $i) { ... }

IP_V6:
   foreach ($ipv6 as $i) { ... }

IP_RANGE:
   # i don't even want to know how you'd implement that

ALLOWED:
   # Wait, is this code even correct?
   # There seems to be a bug in here.
```

And whoever has to debug that code will curse you and your children.

[Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html) puts it like this:

> The unbridled use of the go to statement has as an immediate consequence that it becomes terribly hard to find a meaningful set of coordinates in which to describe the process progress.

And that's why GOTO is considered harmful.

Comment: That `$list_contains_ip = false;` statement seems misplaced

Comment: @Bergi: You're right. That shows how easy it is to mess these things up.

Comment: @whatsisname That bag is called a function/class/package to hold them. using gotos is like juggling them and throwing the bag away.

Comment: I love the quote from Dijkstra, I hadn't heard it put that way but it's a really good point.  Instead of having a flow that's pretty much top to bottom, suddenly you have something that can jump all over the page at random.  Putting it that succinctly is pretty impressive.

Comment: The problem is you mixed state machine with structured elements. When using structured code, goto should only be used for the few cases your programming language doesn't have; most commonly error cleanup (if you don't have exceptions), nested break and retry entire function.

Comment: Nested break can be solved by extracting the loops into a function and retry entire function can be solved with recursion. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by error cleanup, but I'm willing to bet you could avoid `goto` if you thought about it.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser "Error cleanup" probably means the things one would put in the "finally" clause in a try-catch-finally language. The error requires throwing an exception, but there are actions, such as file close, that must be done regardless.

Comment: "And whoever has to debug that code will curse you and your children." Disagree. And as for goto's being easy to mess up, so is all other code. I think people forget that.

Answer (score 40):

There are some legitimate use cases for `GOTO`. For example for error handling and cleanup in C or for implementing some forms of state machines. But this is not one of these cases. The second example is more readable IMHO, but even more readable would be to extract the loop to a separate function and then return when you find a match. Even better would be (in pseudocode, I don't know exact syntax):

```
if (!in_array($ip, $ips)) throw new Exception('Not allowed');
```

So what is so bad about `GOTO`'s? Structured programming uses functions and control structures to organize the code so the syntactic structure reflects the logical structure. If something is only conditionally executed, it will appear in a conditional statement block. If something is executed in a loop, it will appear in a loop block. `GOTO` enables you to circumvent the syntactic structure by jumping around arbitrarily, thereby making the code much harder to follow.

Of course if you have no other choice you use `GOTO`, but if the same effect can be achieved with functions and control structures, it is preferable.

Comment: Re, "Structured programming uses functions and control structures to organize the code so the syntactic structure reflects the logical structure."  You could say exactly the same thing about a program that was a rat's nest of GOTO statements.  Only difference being that the logical structure of the rat's nest program would be BAD logical structure.  So-called "structured programming" is better because it encourages _hierarchical_ design, which turns out to be something that human minds are good at.

Comment: P.S.; ...and also it's easier to write good optimizing compilers for "structured" languages.

Comment: @jameslarge `it's easier to write good optimizing compilers for "structured" languages.` Care to elaborate? As a counter example, the Rust folks introduced [MIR](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/04/19/MIR.html), an intermediate representation in the compiler which specifically replaces loops, continues, breaks, and such with gotos, because it's simpler to check and optimize.

Comment: "if you have no other choice you use GOTO" This would be *exceedingly* rare. I honestly cannot think of a case where you have no other choice, outside of **completely ludicrous** restrictions preventing refactoring existing code or similar nonsense.

Comment: @8bittree, Hmm..., well, that's what I remember them saying back when structured programming was supposed to be the new Silver Bullet.  Maybe they were wrong, or since the people I remember saying it were maintaining [this language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLISS) at the time, and that was way long ago, maybe I'm not remembering it correctly.

Comment: Structured programming is structured because control flows in structured ways, not because of what syntax you use.

Comment: Also, IMO, emulating a `goto` with a rats nest of flags and conditionals (as in the OP's second example) is much less readable than juts using a `goto`.

Comment: @Hurkyl No one is advocating for "a rats nest of flags and conditionals." The best recommendations here are to encapsulate the loop in a function and simply `return` once you know the answer, automatically `break`ing all the loops. It is almost *never* necessary to resort to a "rats nest." If you find yourself doing that, step back and look for better ways to organize your code.

Comment: @Hurkly: Structured programming literally means that the syntax reflects the control flow through the use of blocks, control structures and functions.

Comment: @jameslarge Interesting. So did they specifically design or choose BLISS for ease of optimization, or was it just coincidence that the first optimizing compiler was written for a structured language that lacks `goto`? That *The Design of an Optimizing Compiler* book based on it might be interesting. And, to be fair, MIR is supposed to allow for some optimizations that *cannot* be done at the even lower and simpler LLVM IR level, because they require Rust-specific information that no longer exists at that point.

Comment: @8bittree: Structured programming is intended for the source language, not the compiler's target language.  The target language for native compilers is CPU instructions, which is decidedly *not* "structured," in the programming language sense.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I concur that most machine code is far from structured, but I'm not sure how or if that indicates whether it's easier to optimize a structured source language or an unstructured one.

Comment: @8bittree I believe the compiler optimizations here relate to keeping track of program state. If you can jump to (near) arbitrary locations from (near) arbitrary source locations, the compiler has a much harder time controlling the state, and has to be more cautious in how it optimizes (when reordering statements, writing extra setup/teardown blocks, etc.). Using gotos might have worked for the MIR of Rust due to particulars of how state is constructed there, but it's not a general thing. Most notably, the limited connectivity is already enforced by not exposing gotos to the programmer.

Comment: @8bittree The answer to your question about MIR is in the link you provided: "But it’s fine to have such a construct in MIR, because we know that it will only be used in particular ways, such as to express a loop or a break."  In other words, because goto is not allowed in Rust, they know it is structured and intermediate version with gotos is too.  Ultimately, the code has to get down to goto like machine commands.  What I get from your link is that they are simply adding an incremental step in the conversion from high-level to low-level language.

Comment: @8bittree: BLISS was not the first optimizing compiler, not by a long shot.  High-level languages did not even begin to gain serious traction until someone succeeded in building a compiler that did better optimization than a human assembly language programmer.  That particular milestone happened long before BLISS came along.

Comment: @8bittree because the MIR has been generated from known constructs, the compiler can make a load of assumptions when optimising it. That's not the case if the source is free to GOTO any random address at any time.

Comment: @JimmyJames Hmm... I took that along with the preceding sentence as being more about why `goto` is not in Rust (for safety and maintainability reasons) than about why it's okay in MIR, with the explanation of why it's in MIR is because is a more primitive operation and simple to optimize. But I suppose you might be onto something there. MIR is more than simply an incremental step, though. It's allowing them to easily do optimizations that were unfeasible without it, and even some finer grained checks, to allow some behavior in Rust that is safe, but previously illegal because of no good checks

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Yeah, not sure why I mixed up "first optimizing compiler" with "notably extensive use of optimizations". I seem to recall Fortran was considered unfeasible unless they could get its output fairly close to the performance of typical meat-produced assembly of the day (within 50% maybe?).

Comment: @8bittree I'm pretty sure you are right about why they are doing this and what I mean to suggest is that this incremental step helps them achieve that by moving to something is low level but not machine code. The JVM has bytecode instructions that are jmps/gotos too.  People seem to be missing the point.  All control structures are translated into jumps/gotos but only a subset of these goto approaches are structured.  The high-level control structures ensure that you don't end up with non-structured jumps/gotos and that helps with optimization.

Comment: I know some very talented programmers, much more so than myself (and most people I know consider me to be pretty good at it) but I don't know a single one I'd trust to say "we've gone through it all, and `goto` is the only way" - not one.

Comment: @corsiKa, there’s a proof that any function can be written without goto - by making the code far worse. The question isn’t whether a solution without “goto” is possible, but whether you find a better solution without goto.

Answer (score 18):

As others have said, the problem isn't with the `goto` itself; the problem is with how people use `goto`, and how it can make code harder to understand and maintain.

Assume the following snippet of code:

```
       i = 4;
label: printf( "%d\n", i );
```

What value gets printed for `i`?  *When* does it get printed?  Until you account for *every* instance of `goto label` in your function, you can't know.  The simple presence of that label *destroys* your ability to debug code by simple inspection. For small functions with one or two branches, not much of a problem.  For not-small functions...

Way back in the early '90s we were given a pile of C code that drove a 3d graphical display and told to make it run faster.  It was only about 5000 lines of code, but *all* of it was in `main`, and the author used about 15 or so `goto`s branching in both directions.  This was *bad* code to begin with, but the presence of those `goto`s made it so much worse.  It took my co-worker about 2 weeks to puzzle out the flow of control.  Even better, those `goto`s resulted in code so tightly coupled with itself that we *could not* make any changes without breaking something.

We tried compiling with level 1 optimization, and the compiler ate up all available RAM, then all available swap, and then panicked the system (which probably had nothing to do with the `goto`s themselves, but I like throwing that anecdote out there).

In the end, we gave the customer two options - let us rewrite the whole thing from scratch, or buy faster hardware.

They bought faster hardware.

Bode's rules for using `goto`:

1. Branch forward only;
2. Do not bypass control structures (i.e., do not branch into the body of an `if` or `for` or `while` statement);
3. Do not use `goto` in place of a control structure

There are cases where a `goto` *is* the right answer, but they are rare (breaking out of a deeply nested loop is about the only place I'd use it).

**EDIT**

Expanding on that last statement, here's one of the few valid use cases for `goto`.  Assume we have the following function:

```
T ***myalloc( size_t N, size_t M, size_t P )
{
  size_t i, j, k;

  T ***arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
  for ( i = 0; i < N; i ++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * M );
    for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ )
    {
      arr[i][j] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i][j] * P );
      for ( k = 0; k < P; k++ )
        arr[i][j][k] = initial_value();
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Now, we have a problem - what if one of the `malloc` calls fails midway through?  Unlikely an event as that may be, we don't want to return a partially allocated array, nor do we want to just bail out of the function with an error; we want to clean up after ourselves and deallocate any partially allocated memory.  In a language that throws an exception on a bad alloc, that's fairly straightforward - you just write an exception handler to free up what's already been allocated.

In C, you don't have structured exception handling; you have to check the return value of each `malloc` call and take the appropriate action.

```
T ***myalloc( size_t N, size_t M, size_t P )
{
  size_t i, j, k;

  T ***arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
  if ( arr )
  {
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i ++ )
    {
      if ( !(arr[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i] * M )) )
        goto cleanup_1;

      for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ )
      {
        if ( !(arr[i][j] = malloc( sizeof *arr[i][j] * P )) )
          goto cleanup_2;

        for ( k = 0; k < P; k++ )
          arr[i][j][k] = initial_value();
      }
    }
  }
  goto done;

  cleanup_2:
    // We failed while allocating arr[i][j]; clean up the previously allocated arr[i][j]
    while ( j-- )
      free( arr[i][j] );
    free( arr[i] );
    // fall through

  cleanup_1:
    // We failed while allocating arr[i]; free up all previously allocated arr[i][j]
    while ( i-- )
    {
      for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        free( arr[i][j] );
      free( arr[i] );
    }

    free( arr );
    arr = NULL;

  done:
    return arr;
}
```

Can we do this without using `goto`?  Of course we can - it just requires a little extra bookkeeping (and, in practice, that's the path I'd take).  But, if you're looking for places where using a `goto` isn't *immediately* a sign of bad practice or design, this is one of the few.

Comment: I like these rules.  I still wouldn't use `goto` even in accordance with these rules—I wouldn't use it at *all* unless it's the only form of branching available in the language—but I can see that it wouldn't be too much of a nightmare to debug `goto`'s if they were written according to these rules.

Comment: if you need to break out of a deeply nested loop, you simply need to make that loop another function and return

Comment: As someone once summarized it for me: "It's not a go-to problem, it's a come-from problem". As a software optimization specialist I concur that unstructured control flow can throw compilers (and humans!) for a loop. I once spent hours deciphering a simple state machine (four of five states) in a BLAS function, which used various forms of `GOTO`, including Fortran's (in)famous assigned and arithmetic gotos, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @njuffa "As a software optimization specialist I concur that unstructured control flow can throw compilers (and humans!) for a loop." - any more details? I thought virtually every optimizing compiler nowadays uses SSA as IR which means it's using goto-like code underneath.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I am not a compiler engineer. Yes, modern compilers all seem to use SSA in their intermediate representation. Compilers prefer single-entry-single-exit control constructs, not sure how the use of SSA plays into that? By observation of generated machine code and compiler resource usage, and discussions with compiler engineers unstructured control flow interferes with optimizing code transformations, presumably due to the "come-from" issue. Resource usage (time, memory) can have negative impact on code performance if the compiler decides to skip an optimization as too expensive.

Comment: 1. I've occasionally found it useful to goto jump *above* and *to the outside of control structures*. I think it's usually if not always a bad idea to goto jump to *inside* of a control structure, but jumping to outside often makes sense. Sometimes you have a need to repeat an algorithm from the beginning, and you determine your need to do this somewhere in the middle of the algorithm. 2. I think your argument of having to lookup all of the places where goto is used would apply to a function and its calls as well, but we still use functions. And goto's are limited to inside of a function only!

Answer (score 11):

`return`, `break`, `continue` and `throw`/`catch` are all essentially gotos--they all transfer control to another piece of code and could all be implemented with gotos--in fact I did so once in a school project, a PASCAL instructor was saying how much better Pascal was than basic because of the structure...so I had to be contrary...

The most important thing about Software Engineering (I'm going to use this term over Coding to refer to a situation where you are being paid by someone to create a codebase together with other engineers that requires ongoing improvement and maintenance) is making code Readable--getting it to do something is almost secondary.  Your code will be written only once but, in most cases, people will spend days and weeks revisiting/relearning, improving and fixing it--and every time they (or you) will have to start from scratch and try to remember/figure out your code.

Most of the features that have been added to languages over the years are to make software more maintainable, not easier to write (although some languages go in that direction--they often cause long-term problems...).

Compared to similar flow control statements, GOTOs can be nearly as easy to follow at their best (A single goto used in a case like you suggest), and a nightmare when abused--and are very easily abused...

So after dealing with spaghetti nightmares for a few years we just said "No", as a community we are not going to accept this--too many people mess it up if given a little leeway--that's really the only problem with them. You could use them... but even if it's the perfect case, the next guy will assume you are a terrible programmer because you don't understand the history of the community.

Many other structures have been developed just to make your code more comprehendible: Functions, Objects, Scoping, Encapsulation, Comments(!)... as well as the more important patterns/processes like "DRY" (preventing duplication) and "YAGNI" (Reducing over-generalization/complication of code)--all really only import for the NEXT guy to read your code (Who will probably be you--after you've forgotten most of what you did in the first place!)

Comment: I'm upvoting this just for the sentence, *"The most important thing...is making code Readable; getting it to do something is almost secondary."*  I would say it just slightly differently; it's not so much making code *readable* as [making code *simple*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022251.do).  But either way, it is oh-so-true that making it *do* something is secondary.

Comment: "`return`, `break`, `continue` and `throw`/`catch` are all essentially gotos" Disagree, the former respect the tenets of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) (although you could argue about exceptions), go-to definitely does not. In light of this question, not much is gained by this remark.

Comment: @eric You could model any of the statements with GOTOs.  You could ensure that the GOTOs all agree with structured programming tenets--  they simply have a different syntax and must, in order to exactly duplicate the functionality, include other operations like "if". The advantage of the structured versions is that they are restricted to only supporting certain targets--you KNOW when you see a continue approximately where the target will be located.  The reason I mentioned it was to point out that it's the abusability that is the problem, not that it can't be used correctly.

Comment: Return etc. are *not* essentially gotos. They all adhere to the block and scope structure of the program which gotos's do not - which is exactly why gotos are discouraged. You cannot replace a return with a goto because a goto will not restore the calling scope.

Comment: `return`, `break`, `continue` and `throw`/`catch` are all *subsets* of `goto`. The restriction is the improvement

Comment: What he said. ^ But sometimes restrictions are not improvements...

Answer (score 7):

`GOTO` is a tool. It can be used for good or for evil.

In the bad old days, with FORTRAN and BASIC, it was almost the *only* tool.

When looking at code from those days, when you see a `GOTO` you have to figure out why it is there.  It can be part of a standard idiom that you can understand quickly... or it can be part of some nightmarish control structure that should never have been.  You don't know until you have looked, and it is easy to be mistaken.

People wanted something better, and more advanced control structures was invented.  These covered most of the use cases, and people who were burned by bad `GOTO`s wanted to completely ban them.

Ironically, `GOTO` isn't so bad when it is rare.  When you see one, you **know** there is something special going on, and it is easy to find the corresponding label since it is the only label nearby.

Fast forward to today.  You are a lecturer teaching programming.  You **could** say "In most cases you should use the advanced new constructs, but in some cases a simple `GOTO` can be more readable."  Students are not going to understand that.  They are going to abuse `GOTO` to make unreadable code.

Instead you say "`GOTO` bad. `GOTO` evil.  `GOTO` fail exam."  Students will understand **that**!

Comment: This is in fact true for all deprecated things. Globals. One-letter variable names. Self modifying code. Eval. Even, I suspect, unfiltered user input. Once we have conditioned ourselves to avoid such things like the plague, then we are in a suitable position to evaluate whether a certain use of them, well signposted, might be the correct solution to a specific problem. Before then, we're best off treating them as simply banned.

Answer (score 4):

With the exception of `goto`, all **flow constructs in PHP (and  most languages) are scoped hierarchically.**

Imagine some code examined through squinted eyes:

```
a;
foo {
    b;
}
c;
```

Regardless of what control construct `foo` is (`if`, `while`, etc.), there are only certain allowed orders for `a`, `b`, and `c`.

You could have `a`-`b`-`c`, or `a`-`c`, or even `a`-`b`-`b`-`b`-`c`. But you could **never** have `b`-`c` or `a`-`b`-`a`-`c`.

...unless you have `goto`.

```
$a = 1;
first:
echo 'a';
if ($a === 1) {
    echo 'b';
    $a = 2;
    goto first;
}
echo 'c';
```

`goto` (in particular backwards `goto`) can be troublesome enough that it's best to just leave it alone, and used hierarchical, blocked flow constructs.

`goto`s have a place, but mostly as micro-optimizations in low-level languages. IMO, there's no good place for it in PHP.

---

FYI, the example code can be written even better than either of your suggestions.

```
if(!in_array($ip, $ips, true)) {
    throw new Exception('Not allowed');
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I've deliberately coded like in your goto example, specifically for readability and maintainability. There are legitimate cases. Also, I've always found exceptions to be a headache to work with, and for them to have very poor maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with `goto` statements themselves. The wrongs are with some of the people that inappropriately use the statement.

In addition to what JacquesB said (error handling in C), you are using `goto` to exit a non-nested loop, something that you can do by using `break`. In this case you better use `break`.

But if you had a nested loop scenario, then using `goto` would be more elegant/simpler.

**Bonous point:** if your list of IPs is small, your method is fine. But if the list grows, know that your approach has an asymptotic worst run-time complexity of **O(n)**. As your list grows, you may wish to use a different method that achieves **O(log n)** (such as a tree structure) or **O(1)** (a hash table with no collisions).

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP, but many languages will support using `break` and `continue` with a number (to break/continue that many layers of loops) or a label (to break/continue the loop with that label), either of which should generally be preferable to using `goto` for nested loops.

Comment: @8bittree good point. I didn't know that PHP's **break** is that fancy. I only know C's **break** isn't that fancy. Perl's **break** (they call it **last**) also used to be similar to C's (i.e. not fancy as PHP's) but it -too- became fancy after some point. I guess my answer is getting less and less useful as more languages are introducing fancy versions of **break** :)

Comment: a break with a depth value wouldn't resolve the issue without the extra variable.  A variable in its self that creates an extra level of complexity.

Comment: Of course, just because you have nested loops does not mean you need a goto, there are other ways of elegantly handling that situation.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Could you please offer an example of a nested loop that you can exit without using a **goto** statement, while also using a language that does not have a fancy version of **break** that specifies depth?

Comment: @caveman look at your example code.  Then look at `allowed = ips.Any(ip => ips2.Contains(ip));` Why do I need a goto again?

Comment: @NPSF3000 - Sorry for the 5 many years late reply.  I just deleted the code, because I don't have time to read it, and because I don't use PHP anyway.  I forgot what was I thinking when I wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

In low level languages GOTO is inevitable. But in high level it should be avoided (in the case the language supports it) because **it makes programs more difficult to read**.

**Everything boils down to making the code more difficult to read.** High level languages are supossedt o make code easier to read than low level languages like, say, assembler or C.

GOTO doesn't cause global warming nor it causes poverty in the third world. **It just makes code more difficult to read.**

Most modern languages have control structures that make GOTO unnecessary. Some like Java don't even have it.

In fact, the term *spaguetti code* comes from convoluted, difficult to follow code causes by unstructured branching structures.

Comment: `goto` can make code eaiser to read.  When you created extra variables and nested branches versus a single jump the code is much more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Perhaps if you have a single goto in a ten line method. But most methods are not ten lines long and most of the times when people use GOTO  they don't use it "just this once".

Comment: @MatthewWhited In fact, the term *spaguetti code* comes from convoluted, difficult to follow code caused by unstructured branching structures. Or is spaguetti code easier to red now? Maybe. Vinyl is returning, why wouldn't GOTO.

Comment: @Tulains I have to believe such bad things exist because people keep complaining about then, but most of the times I see `goto` come up are not examples of convoluted spaghetti code, but instead fairly straightforward things, often emulating patterns of control flow in languages that don't have the syntax for it: the two most common examples are to break out of multiple loops and the example in the OP where `goto` is used to implement `for`-`else`.

Comment: Unstructured spaghetti code comes from languages where functions/methods don't exist.  
`goto` is also great for things such as exception retry, rollback, state machines.

Comment: @MatthewWhited what makes you think that creating extra variables is the correct solution?  If Y is bad and X is Bad, then X > Y doesn't suddenly make Y good.

Comment: I don't.  I am one of the people saying goto can create cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

> With goto I can write faster code!

True. Don't care.

> Goto exists in assembly! They just call it jmp.

True. Don't care.

> Goto solves problems more simply.

True. Don't care.

> In the hands of a disciplined developer code that uses goto can be easier to read.

True. However, I've been that disciplined coder.  I've seen what happens to code over time.  `Goto` starts out fine.  Then the urge to reuse code sets in.  Fairly soon I find myself at a breakpoint having no damn clue what's going on even after looking at program state.   `Goto` makes it hard to reason about code.  We've worked really hard creating `while`, `do while`, `for`, `for each` `switch`, `subroutines`, `functions`, and more all because doing this stuff with `if` and `goto` is hard on the brain.

So no. We don't want to look at `goto`.  Sure it's alive and well in the binary but we don't need to see that in source.  In fact, `if` is starting to look a little shaky.

Comment: "Goto solves problems more simply." / "True. Don't care." - I'd hate to see your code where you deliberately avoid simple solutions in favour of what is most extensible. (Heard of YAGNI?)

Comment: Actually goto is the more extensible one.  It's more powerful and more expressive.  It's still a bad idea.  Sorry but less is more here.

Comment: Your "meat" paragraph (second to last) is the best one here.  I don't agree that "`goto` solves problems more simply."  And I don't know why `if` would be looking shaky.  (In which language?)

Comment: @Wildcard if and goto are very simple ways to solve problems best solved other ways.  They are low hanging fruit.  It's not about the particular language. `Goto` lets you abstract a problem by making it some other bit of codes problem.  `If` lets you choose that abstraction.  There are better ways to abstract and better ways to choose the abstraction.  [Polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1493294) for one.

Comment: Although I agree with you, this is a poorly worded answer. "True, don't care" is not a convincing argument for anything. I think your main message is this: although goto is appealing to people who prefer using efficient, powerful tools, it leads to a surprisingly huge amount of wasted time later on, even when care is taken.

Comment: @artelius The "true, don't care" theme isn't meant to be convincing.  It's meant to illustrate the many points I'll concede to goto and still come down against it.  Thus arguing those points with me is pointless.  Since that's not my point.  Get the point?

Comment: I just believe that a good answer doesn't just state your opinion, but also explains it, and allows the reader to make his own judgement. As it stands, it's unclear _why_ goto's good points aren't enough to outweigh its problems. Most of us have spent hours of hair-pulling trying to find bugs that _don't_ involve goto. It's not the only construct that's hard to reason about. Someone asking this question is probably much less experienced and needs things put in perspective.

Comment: I did explain it. In what you called the meat. Yes not using goto won't guarantee you can follow your code.  Avoiding goto simply makes tracing program flow easier.  Doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: And adding extra variables and loops just to avoid a short jump makes code much more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @MatthewWhited that's been proven to not be necessary.  But there is no form in which to express working code that some coder can't turn into an unreadable mess.  Using goto just makes it easier to create that mess.  The work you are forced to do when you avoid goto is time well spent because it makes the pattern you are using easier to recognize.

Comment: jacking around with some keywords such as while, do/while, for and so on with a sprinkling of of extra flow control and variables does not make code easier to read.

http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/Literature/knuthProgramming1974.pdf

Comment: It does when you do it right. Next time try reading what you link to before you link to it.  "In all cases tried, however, the program without the goto statement turned out to be shorter and more lucid." p265

Comment: Really what this all boils down to is "bad coders should not be allowed to code."

Comment: Sigh, no. Bad coders can make anything bad.  That says nothing about goto either way.  Goto just makes writing bad code to easy.  Once it works you are far less likely to make it any better.  Loop structures ask a little more from you. But they are no guarantee.

Comment: I can summarize my thoughts about your answer as, "Don't care."

Answer (score -1):

Assembly languages typically have only conditional/unconditional jumps (the equivalent of GOTO. Older implementations of FORTRAN and BASIC had no control block statements beyond a counted iteration (the DO loop), leaving all other control flow to IFs and GOTOs. The DO loop in these languages was terminated by a numerically labeled statement. As a result, code written for these languages could be, and often was, hard to follow and prone to mistakes.

To underscore the point, there is the facetiously invented "[COME FROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM)" statement.

There is practically no need to use GOTO in languages like C, C++, C#, PASCAL, Java, etc.; alternative constructions can be used which will almost certainly be just as efficient and far more maintainable. It's true that one GOTO in a source file will not be a problem. The problem is that it doesn't take many to make a unit of code difficult to follow and error-prone to maintain. That's why the accepted wisdom is to avoid GOTO whenever possible.

This [wikipedia article on the goto statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) might be helpful